# Explanation needed for a calculation

Tags: python

I am fairly new to Python and do not understand the explanation given by the course I am doing. I cannot follow why width gets 2.

To my understanding the `print(combine(1)[2])` appoints the value to to position one. But I thought `is_3D` is in position 0, hence height would be in position 2.
So I do not understand what is going on here.

```
def combine(width, height=2, depth=0, is_3D=False):
    return[is_3D, width, height, depth]
print(combine(1)[2])
```

[image]

Comment: Your question does not show any research effort, so it does need -1. Just saying. Also _So I do not understand what is going on here_  is unclear about which part of the code you not understand.

Comment: `combine(1)` calls `combine` with its first argument, `width`, set to 1. The description of another behaviour is unclear.

Comment: The explanation contains an error: `width` is assigned `1` by the call. Apart from that it is rather easy to understand.

Comment: Exactly, the explanation has an error. As I mentioned in my explanation & investigation:  I cannot follow why width gets 2? To my understanding the print(combine(1)[2]) appoints the value to to position one. But I thought is_3D is in position 0, hence height would be in position 2

Comment: I don't see any tuples in your code

Comment: The explanation given to this (as copied in above) says there is one

Comment: `height` is in position 2, right. And `height` got a default value if it isn't overwritten by the call (which it isn't here).

Comment: @Anna The image (the so-called explanation) states that a tuple is returned and yet it shows a list. If I was still learning basic Python I'd look for a course that gives accurate information

Comment: Thank you @Michael Butscher  - I spent far too much time to try and  work out the result given by the course provider. And good to see I could just not make sense of the explanation given by the provider, as it is simply wrong.

Comment: @Pingu   - Python Institute - should be pretty good. Hence I am surprised their explanation contains such a  mistake.

Comment: Generally you should use another course or tutorial. The shown explanation has two errors about a rather simple code sample. It probably won't become better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a code answering your question, see below.

Short answer - `return[is_3D, width, height, depth]` reorders the input parameters of this function inside the list. At the end, you are asking to print an element in position [2], which is 'height'. Height has a default value of 2 and is a [keyword argument](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-argument) with a default value of 2. Which results in the output of 2.
I added logging to the code, which is best practice and can be useful.

```py
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')


def combine(width, height=2, depth=0, is_3D=False):
    logging.info(f'width = {width}')
    logging.info(f'height = {height}')
    logging.info(f'height = {depth}')
    logging.info(f'is_3D = {is_3D}')

    return [is_3D, width, height, depth]


returned_list = combine(1)
logging.info(f'return of the function is {returned_list}')
print(returned_list[2])
```

```bash
2023-02-03 13:24:52,069 - root - INFO - width = 1
2023-02-03 13:24:52,069 - root - INFO - height = 2
2023-02-03 13:24:52,069 - root - INFO - height = 0
2023-02-03 13:24:52,069 - root - INFO - is_3D = False
2023-02-03 13:24:52,069 - root - INFO - return of the function is [False, 1, 2, 0]
2
```

Answer (score 4):

You call *combine()* with a value of 1. Thus, within the function, width will be equal to 1. All other local variables will take their default values.

You return a list of values. The *height* value (which defaulted to 2) is at index 2 in that list.

That's why the output of your print is 2 - i.e., it's the (default) value of *height*

Comment: To make this super clear:
combine(1)[0] = is_3d = False;
combine(1)[1] = width = 1;  - this is the value you passed to the function
combine(1)[2] = height - 2;   - this is the default value of height as per the function definition